# How can "profiling" be done in a dataset? What are the different techniques?

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction, data-analysis

I am currently doing an analysis in which I need to "profile" each record. For example, let's say I have a dataset of accounts with customer information (name, id, address, money spent, products bought, etc).In my real case there are 100+ features. The customers are already labelled as "good" or "bad". A good customer is whomever spent more than $10k for example. However, before jumping into building a classification model, I'd like to profile each customer to answer the questions: How does a "good" customer look like? How does a "bad" customer look like?.
What would be the analysis techniques that could be used for this scenario?

Comment: how about clustering techniques on the dataset?

Comment: An efficient solution is to do random forest classification in order to group the main scenarios automatically. https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-forest-ensemble-in-python/

Comment: So doing unsupervised learning on the dataset seems the way to go